# Argo workflowtemplate timeout

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

Tried Argo Workflow template with both timeout and activeDeadlineSeconds and this template also has retryStrategy. In both case, timeout are applied for each run but I want  entire template should timeout within mentioned time. How to achieve this? Please comment in case the question is not clear.

```
kind: WorkflowTemplate
.
.
spec:
  templates:
    -name: taskA
     activeDeadlineSeconds :30
     retryStrategy:
       limit: 2
     .....
```

In this, all retry in case of timeout runs for 30sec each. But I wanted the entire workflowTemplate to timeout after 30 sec. Not 90sec. Is there any reference for this?

Answer (score 1):

`activeDeadlineSeconds` can also be used in the Workflow/WorkflowTemplate level, see an example [here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/timeouts-workflow.yaml).

Comment: Links break, please [edit] the answer to include the relevant sample section from the documentation (in addition to having the link you already listed.)

Comment: see also https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/walk-through/timeouts/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks got it. activeDeadlineSeconds can be used directly under spec: outside templates: level to achieve this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).